# How can I append more data to a JSON encoded array created from SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, json

I have a query that is sent to my SQL database from PHP. It looks something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

I ultimately return the json_encoded result to my Java application (Android, actually) so that I can pick apart the pieces and put them into a nice Java object.

I have come to a point where I need some more data to come from this query, and I don't know how to get it. Is there a way for me to give myself the results of ANOTHER query, and inject it into this json_encoded result? Like basically run another query, and append it to the `$r` on each iteration of the loop and have it "seem" as if it was another column returned from the original queries `select`? I just don't know how to handle this `$rows[]` array.

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Add mutiple levels to your PHP array:

```
$data = array();

$data['part1'] = 'data from query 1';
$data['part2'] = 'data from query 2';

echo json_encode($data);
```

then simply refer to those sub-arrays in your client-side code.

Comment: I think I almost got it - so is the key defined with your code? On the client I would do `json_data.getString("part1")`? Like when you do `$data['part1']` above is that creating a new key at the end of the array called `part1`?

Comment: more like `json_data.part1[3]` would be the 4th row of data from your query results.